# Consulta em tabela com CONCAT e JOIN?

Tags: laravel, join

Preciso obter um `collection` como resultado de consulta em **3** tabelas usando `concat` e `join`, a imagem abaixo mostra o relacionamento entre elas:

> [image: tabelas do banco]

tentei usar o codigo abaixo

```
$teste = DB::table('clientes as c')
      ->leftjoin('reservas as r', 'r.codReserva', '=', 'b.ce_denunciacrime')
      ->leftjoin('produtos as p', 'p.codProduto', '=', 'r.codReserva')
      ->select('p.codProduto','r.codReserva',
                DB::raw("CONCAT(c.codCliente,', ') as codCliente"))
      ->limit(1)
      ->get();

dd($teste);
```

o `array` de resultado deveria ser algo assim:

```
#items: array:1[
0 => {#498 
  +"codProduto": 1
  +"codReserva": 2
  +"codCliente": 20,30,40
}]
```

---

Imagine essa tabela abaixo, o resultado seria as duas primeiras colunas mais a concatenação dos valores da terceira, tendo como resultado o `array` mostrado acima.

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>codProduto</th><th>codReserva</th><th>codCliente</th>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td><td>2</td><td>30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td><td>2</td><td>40</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: O codCliente junta todos os números!? Explique melhor.

Comment: isso. a coluna codCliente ficaria: "20,30,40"...

Answer (score 3):

consegui resolver usando 'GROUP_CONCAT' como na consulta abaixo:

```
$teste = DB::table('clientes as c')
    ->leftjoin('reservas as r', 'r.codReserva', '=', 'b.ce_denunciacrime')
    ->leftjoin('produtos as p', 'p.codProduto', '=', 'r.codReserva')
    ->select('p.codProduto','r.codReserva',
              DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(c.codCliente,'') as codCliente"))
    ->limit(1)
    ->groupBy('p.codProduto','r.codReserva')
    ->get();

dd($teste);
```